# How to add new country in sitecore commerce 10

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I am trying to add new country in sitecore commerce, so I made changes in below areas:

- Added new country under `/sitecore/Commerce/Commerce Control Panel/Shared Settings/Countries-Regions`
- Selected the country in `/sitecore/Commerce/Commerce Control Panel/Storefront Settings/Storefronts/Storefront/Country-Region Configuration`.
  [image]
  But while trying to select the State **India** in live site ,I am getting the below error.

[image]

can anyone help me to resolve this?

Comment: The `3 letter ISO 3066 code` code for India is `IND`.

Comment: Thankyou for Your quick response, I have tried that as well

Comment: @MarkCassidy I have updated the screenshot .please check that. I got same issue even after change the Country code as IND.

Comment: Did you try to Synchronize content items - https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/91/sitecore-experience-commerce/synchronize-content-items.html